# setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter.... Doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello i get The constructor ArrayAdapter(FragmentBlue, int, String[]) is undefined

in this particular code

```
package com.example.babycare;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class FragmentBlue extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle {

    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private ListView drawerListView;

    private static final String TAG = FragmentBlue.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
        return view;

        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
        drawerListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPauseFragment()"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResumeFragment()");

    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because a fragment is not a context.

Comment: thefore how should i put it ? with getActivity() instead of this it makes me delete drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items); Says its unreachable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using a fragment you have to get the activity context:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);

    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
    drawerListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));


    return view;
}
```

Comment: After i put getActivity() it wants me to delete drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items); Says its unreachable

Comment: you need to put the return view at the end of the statement block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));
```

instead of

```
drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));
```

Replace `this` with `getActivity`

Comment: After i put getActivity() it wants me to delete
drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

Says its unreachable

Comment: you should learn the basics. return view; should be your end statement